# Xenserver 6.5: kernel panic - noapic parameter is incompatible with Xen

Tags: xenserver, citrix

Currently I have a server and I want to install XenServer on it, the problem is that I get a kernel panic during the installation procedure. `'kernel panic - not syncing: the noapic parameter is incompatible with Xen.'`

So I've traced it to the point where I can't fix it anymore:

- I've disabled ACPI & the APIC intrupt system in the bios, did not work
- I've tried disabling the APIC, LAPIC & APCI mentioned here in a official discussion. http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/350144-xen62-turn-off-acpi-without-grubconfmenulst/

The error keeps popping up and I clearly need some insight why this error keeps occuring.

Error dump: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiqNA.jpg

**EDIT:** Currently I'm really considering the rewrite the Xen kernel and delete that piece of garbage error

**UPDATE:** I downloaded Xenserver 5.5 and I could succesfully install it!

Comment: Which hardware are you trying to install XenServer 6.5?

Comment: I've obtained some old hardware from the company that I work for, it has never been used: Zenith BDR 3100R G2 (http://www.pyramiddec.com/shop/shopexd.asp?id=68179), the quadcores are AMD Opteron 2347 HE

Comment: Are you using safe mode to install? Are you manually passing in the "noapic" parameter?

Comment: Crosspost on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/3h0sjt/xenserver_65_kernel_panic_noapic_parameter_is/